# Work around possible for view report history permission?

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, permissions

I have a number of SSRS reports hosted in SharePoint for which I have set up a 10 snapshot rolling history, with the intention of allowing the end user to be able to access, display and export, historical reports of recent vintage.

However, upon researching the matter, it appears that the View permissions set, which is the current permissions level that all end users are currently assigned, is insufficient to view report histories and instead Edit permissions are required.

Am I reading that correctly? It seems odd that "view report history" wouldn't be contained in the View permissions set and would instead require Edit permissions, which, overall, is a set of permissions I don't want the general end user to possess.

If true, is there any possible work around, or method to granting just the permission to "view report history"? I'd really prefer to not have to pull the reports personally any time someone wanted to see one of the historical snapshots, but granting edit permissions is simply not an option.

Answer (score 1):

View Permissions privilege should be more than enough to retrieve what you need.

I created a sample site based on your description and here is what I had to configure to make this work:

1. [Created a custom permission level](http://office.microsoft.com/en-001/sharepoint-server-help/edit-create-and-delete-permission-levels-HA101805381.aspx) with the following privileges:

   - View Items  -  View items in lists and documents in document libraries.
   - Open Items  -  View the source of documents with server-side file handlers.
   - View Versions  -  View past versions of a list item or document.
   - View Application Pages  -  View forms, views, and application pages. - Enumerate lists.
   - View Pages  -  View pages in a Web site.
   - Open  -  Allows users to open a Web site, list, or folder in order to access items inside that container.
2. User was given these permission via group

You can find the final result below. As you can see this user can view versions but cannot manage permissions. I have been using SharePoint Online for this test, but these features haven't changed much since SharePoint 2007.

[image: Items visible to user with custom permissions]

Comment: Unfortunately, I'm not looking to set permissions to allow view "Version History", which I believe is already native in the "View" permissions, I want to allow "View Report History". [This](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb326286.aspx) MSFT document seems to make clear that requires "Edit" and not just "View".